# How to bind to an element after creating it dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events, dom-manipulation

I have this code:

```
$(".div").click(function ()
{
    alert("hi");
});
```

...but when I create new `div`:

```
$("body").append("<div>1</div>");
```

...and click on this `div`, it doesn't say "hi".

I know that I can do `onclick="callfunction()"` on the `div` element, but I would like to avoid using that method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problems**

You were attempting to create a bind on an element that didn't yet exist - so it couldn't be bound.

You used `.div` as a selector. The selector `.div` is looking for an element with `class="div"` rather than an element of type `div`.

---

**Solution 1 - Delegation**
With delegation you create a bind on an element that exists in the structure above where you will be dynamically adding an element that you want to listen for.

To use delegation, change to this:

```
$("body").on("click", "div", function ()
{
    alert("hi");
});
```

Here is an example showing delegation vs binding on a future element without delegation:
[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HXa7C/)

---

**Solution 2 - Bind to element on creation**
The alternative would be to add the bind on the creation of the new element, that would look something like this:

```
$newEle = $("<div>1</div>").click( function() {
    alert("hi");
});
$("body").append($newEle);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tSbJG/)

Comment: I tried: $("#table").on("click", "div[x][y]", function () { }); and it doesn't work, why?

Comment: parameters of my div ( my div looks like that: <div x="2" y="3">...</div> but even if i do $("body").on("click", "div", function () { }); it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, where do you have this js code? Within a `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: they are attributes, why its not proper?

Comment: its weird, in jsfiddle it works but in my project it doesn't :\

Comment: @user2689573, I don't know why that wouldn't work as long as the bind is made after the document is loaded and all the selectors match your dom. I added an alternative to my original solution though, see if that works for you. Also, are you checking for console errors?

Answer (score 0):

Use the appendChild() method to add the DIV to the end of your document. See: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Your other logic can follow the creation of the div.